# Pushing metadata (say, via tags/notes) automatically in Git (w/o using a client-side hook)?

Tags: git, metadata, push

I need to pass some metadata about the commits that are being pushed. Is there a way to push metadata along with push operation? Of course, one can create a tag/note in post-commit or pre-push hook.

But, is there a way to pass the metadata w/o using the client-side hooks? Or, is there any other means apart from notes/tag to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Git decides what to push in two steps:

1. If there's an explicit refspec passed to `git push`, it is used.
2. Otherwise, Git looks for a bunch of variables in the repository's configuration trying to make out what to push and what to update in the remote repository with what is being pushed. (The whole thing is complicated so let's not touch it).

So basically instead of

```
git push origin master
```

you could do

```
git push origin master refs/notes/*
```

to push only the branch "master" and any Git notes, or do

```
git config --add remote.origin.push refs/heads/*
git config --add remote.origin.push refs/notes/*
git config --add remote.origin.push refs/tags/*
```

so a simple

```
git push origin
```

would push all the (local) branches, notes and tags.

Consider reading the `git-push(1)` manual carefully: it's somewhat dry but is to the point and explains how refspecs are interpreted and how `remote.<name>.push` and `push.default` affect the operation.

Comment: It could be done via the command line, I know. But, the thing is how would one do it automatically while using other Git clients - say, EGit in Eclipse, XCode or IntelliJ? (Do not want to resort to some IDE specific operation).

Perhaps, updating the push refspec in the repository config file might be the only option. However, the problem still exist, as to how you create the metadata (i.e., the tag or notes with a predefined refspec namespace)